# Если убрать два тире, предложение рассыплется?

Tags: пунктуация

> Мне было важно уберечься от современной ангажированной истории,
>   избежать всевозможных – полезных то одному, то другому дню – подходов
>   к историческим фактам.

Нужно ко "всевозможным" добавить определение (сохранив тем тире), - какое?

---

О.

ЛУКАВЫХ годится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй ответ

Сейчас я написала бы так:

*Мне было важно уберечься от современной ангажированной истории, избежать  **пристрастных/предвзятых** – полезных то одному, то другому дню – подходов к историческим фактам.*

***Всевозможный*** – это слишком объемная и невыполнимая задача, слово здесь лишнее. Ведь тема уже обозначена – ангажированный подход, нужен синоним для усиления этого значения.

***Лукавый*** – вроде бы по стилю не очень подходит, это как бы хитрый, обманный.

Answer (score 1):

Мне было важно уберечься от современной ангажированной истории, избежать всевозможных – **полезных то одному, то другому дню** – подходов к историческим фактам.

http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_22.htm#ppp_4

(п.4)  На площадку классного вагона вышел человек в чёрной — **до ворота застёгнутой** — гимнастёрке (А. Т.);

Я думаю, что обособить можно любое определение с уточняющим значением, в том числе и распространенное.

Можно считать, что это вставка, обособление двумя тире.

**Но без двух тире не получится,** так как определение распространенное и имеет  собственные знаки.

Comment: Ааа, караул. Если нутро двух тир считать уточнением, имеем: ***избежать всевозможных подходов к историческим фактам***!

Comment: Да, неувязочка вышла. Надо подобрать другое определение, например "предвзятых".

Comment: Ну, автор тебя любит, пусть думает. Я-то предложила ***лукавых***.