# Пояснения запятых

Tags: пунктуация

> Он, в сущности, является далеко не синонимичным глаголу «улыбаться», так как с ним связан оттенок «усмехаться, иронически, слегка пренебрежительно, как бы себе на уме улыбаться».

Как объяснить запятую после "усмехаться" и после "пренебрежительно"?

Comment: А как бы вы это объяснили (или отсутствие этих запятых)?

Comment: 1) обособленное опредение 2)придаточное сравнения

Answer (score 2):

После "пренебрежительно" как раз всё просто.

Всё смущающее - пересказ этого оттенка: *усмехаться, иронически, слегка пренебрежительно, как бы себе на уме улыбаться.*

Только парочку *усмехаться/улыбаться* в этом контексте я разделила бы не запятой (постановку которой можно оставить на совести автора), а иным знаком:

усмехаться; иронически, слегка пренебрежительно, как бы себе на уме улыбаться,

где *иронически, слегка пренебрежительно, как бы себе на уме* относятся именно к последнему слову (улыбаться *как*: перверсия).

Comment: Я вас только дополнила в части подробного грамматического анализа. Честно говоря, я просто заранее написала ответ, когда вашего ответа  еще не видела. Но ведь вы не обидитесь на меня, правда?  Я люблю, когда вы сюда заходите. Мур-мур, извините...

Comment: Шарончик, что дополнила - не беда, мур-мур. Я органически избегаю многословия; разве не очевидно, что всё ***необходимое*** мною сказано? Есть ли нужда у вопрошальщика в грамматическом анализе? Я говорю с ним, а ты - с человечеством. Но шапка вопроса его сюда не приведёт, не-а. Шапку, кароч, правь.

Comment: Доправь свой ответ, пока не затерялся - https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453502/%d0%95%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f ЛОшкой дам!

Comment: Слушаюсь и повинуюсь, не надо меня ложкой…

Comment: Где - слушаюсь, где - повинуюсь: шапочку, грю, поправь!

Comment: Шапочку-кепочку…А можно на бумажечке написать сам текстик, пжста (как поправить и какой из ответов). А еще лучше поправьте сами, пжста, у меня сейчас будут проблемы со временем, не знаю, когда смогу зайти.

Answer (score 2):

Я **согласна** с первым ответом: всё объясняется верно; действительно, поставить точку с запятой имеет смысл. В своем же ответе я дополнительно приведу подробный **грамматический анализ** предложения (для интересующихся).

***Он, в сущности, является далеко не синонимичным глаголу «улыбаться», так как с ним связан оттенок  (какой?) «усмехаться; иронически, слегка пренебрежительно, как бы себе на уме улыбаться».***

Пояснение грамматики:

1. В кавычках дается несогласованное **определение**, отнесенное к слову «глаголу».
2. Определение включает  два ряда однородных членов:
   (1) Два инфинитива: усмехаться, улыбаться. Бессоюзная связь, которую мы обозначили точкой с запятой;

(2)  Три  **обстоятельства образа действия**, выраженных двумя наречиями и фразеологическим оборотом (к обороту относится частица КАК БЫ): улыбаться (как?) иронически, пренебрежительно, как бы себе на уме. Бессоюзная связь, обозначенная запятыми.

3. **Обоснование** точки с запятой

Конечно, грамматику можно понять и с одними запятыми, но сложнее. К тому же в устной речи все равно надо сделать **увеличенную паузу,** иначе смысл будет неясен. При наличии только запятых это придется сделать читающему текст, но будет лучше, если это сделает его **автор.**